# How to categorized data in pandas using contained keywords

Tags: python, pandas

Let `df` be the dataframe as follows:

```
      date   text
0  2019-6-7  London is good.             
1  2019-5-8  I am going to Paris.        
2  2019-4-4  Do you want to go to London?
3  2019-3-7  I love Paris!
```

I would like to add a column `city`, which indicates the city contained in `text`, that is,

```
       date  text                          city
0  2019-6-7  London is good.               London
1  2019-5-8  I am going to Paris.          Paris 
2  2019-4-4  Do you want to go to London?  London
3  2019-3-7  I love Paris!                 Paris
```

How to do it without using `lambda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first match sure you have the list of city , then `str.findall`

```
df.text.str.findall('London|Paris').str[0]
Out[320]: 
0    London
1     Paris
2    London
3     Paris
Name: text, dtype: object
df['city'] = df.text.str.findall('London|Paris').str[0]
```

Comment: Next step is `df.groupby('city')['date'].max()` but it only contains `date` and `city` but not `text`. How to include all columns?

Comment: @Chan `df.loc[df.groupby('city')['date'].idxmax()]` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @WenYoBen's method, if there is only either of Paris or London in one text then [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is better:

```
regex = '(London|Paris)'
df['city'] = df.text.str.extract(regex)
df

       date         text                        city
0   2019-6-7    London is good.                 London
1   2019-5-8    I am going to Paris.            Paris
2   2019-4-4    Do you want to go to London?    London
3   2019-3-7    I love Paris!                   Paris
```

And if you want all the cities in your regex in a text then [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) is an option too:

```
df['city'] = df.text.str.extractall(regex).values
df
          date  text                           city
0    2019-6-7   London is good.                London
1    2019-5-8   I am going to Paris.           Paris
2    2019-4-4   Do you want to go to London?   London
3    2019-3-7   I love Paris!                  Paris
```

Note that if there are multiple matches, the extractall will return a list